# Trying to authenticate a service account with firebase-admin from a Cloud Scheduler call? Error: Firebase ID token has incorrect "iss" (issuer) claim

Tags: firebase, service-accounts, google-cloud-run, google-iam, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm trying to authenticate an API call made to my server (on Cloud Run) from a Cloud Scheduler cron job.

I'm trying to use a service account to this.

**Note:** this is all happening inside the same Project.

**References:**

- https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth

This is what I'm doing:

**STEP 1** - Create the service account

I went to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials and created a new service account. I've assigned the role as `owner`.

[image]

**STEP 2** - Create the cron job.

I went to https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler to create the cron job like I always do.

[image]

In the `service account` field I've put my service account e-mail. In the `Audience` field, I've put my project id because at some point I got an error saying that it was expecting it to be the name of my project id.

This was the error:

> Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected `"PROJECT_ID"`

**STEP 3** - Running the job and identify decoding the token:

This is the code on my server:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(
    // THIS IS THE DEFAULT FIREBASE-ADMIN SERVICE ACCOUNT
    // THAT IS AUTOMATICALLY CREATED BY FIREBASE
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT as admin.ServiceAccount
)});

// THIS IS THE CODE THAT IS INSIDE MY SERVER TRYING TO VERIFY THE SERVICE ACCOUNT

try {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  console.log(`authHeader: ${authHeader}`);
  if (authHeader) {
    const idToken = authHeader.split(" ")[1];   // GETS THE USER ID TOKEN
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    console.log(`decodedToken: ${decodedToken}`);
  }
}
```

And this is the error I'm currently getting:

> Firebase ID token has incorrect "iss" (issuer) claim. Expected "https://securetoken.google.com/"my-project-id" but got "https://accounts.google.com". Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm doing it? Should I not be using firebase-admin to this?

Should I be using `google-auth-library` to verify the token?

- https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#verifying-id-tokens
- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

[image]

Comment: for people using firebase sdk -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39193057/5806017

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a morning in hell trying to debug this, here is what I've found.

It seems that `firebase-admin`'s `admin.auth().verifyIdToken()` only works for tokens generated from the `firebase` SDK.

I got it to work by using the `google-auth-library` directly.

I did the following.

**NOTE:** The rest of the code is the same (using the same service account as described in the question):

```
import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";

export const apiExpressRouteHandler: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const PROJECT_ID = process.env.PROJECT_ID;

    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (authHeader) {
      const client = new OAuth2Client(PROJECT_ID);
      const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: authHeader.split(" ")[1],
        audience: PROJECT_ID
      });

      // LOGGING ticket PROPERTIES

      console.log(`userId: ${JSON.stringify(ticket.getUserId())}`);
      console.log(`payload: ${JSON.stringify(ticket.getPayload())}`);
      console.log(`envelope: ${JSON.stringify(ticket.getEnvelope())}`);
      console.log(`attributes: ${JSON.stringify(ticket.getAttributes())}`);
    }

    // REST OF THE CODE
  }
} 
catch(err) {
  // ...
}
```

I'm not sure if the `PROJECT_ID` is necessary to initialize the client with `new OAuth2Client(PROJECT_ID);` but it is working like this.

Comment: for people using firebase sdk -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39193057/5806017