# Google Sign-In idToken with createSessionCookie causing error - there is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication

**Stack:**

- Google Sign-in (Vanilla JS - client side),
- Firebase Functions (ExpressJS)

**Client-Side:**

My Firebase function express app uses vanilla javascript on the client side. To authenticate I am making use of Firebase's Google SignIn feature client-side javascript web apps, found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin).

```
// Firebase setup
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIza...",
    authDomain: "....firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://...-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    ...
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);    
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);

function postIdTokenToSessionLogin(idToken, csrfToken) {
    return axios({
        url: "/user/sessionLogin",                < ----- endpoint code portion found below
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            idToken: idToken,
            csrfToken: csrfToken,
        },
    });
}

// ...

// On sign-in click
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(async value => {
        const idToken = value.credential.idToken;
        const csrfToken = getCookie('_csrf');
        return postIdTokenToSessionLogin(idToken, csrfToken);
    }).then(value => {
        window.location.assign("/user/dashboard")
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
    });
```

*Note I am using `value.credential.idToken` (most sources imply to use this, but haven't found an example saying use this specifically)*

**Directly after calling `signInWithPopup`**, a new account is created in my Firebase Console Authentication matching the gmail account that was just signed in.

**Server-side:**

Once I authenticate, I create an `axios` request passing in the `{user}.credential.idToken` and following the server-side setup [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) (ignoring the CSRF - this just doesn't want to work).

In creating the session, I use the following code in my firebase functions express app, the endpoint which is `router.post('/sessionLogin', (req, res) =>`  (part of `/user` route prefix):

```
// Set session expiration to 5 days.
const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();   // eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImt...[936]

admin
    .auth()
    .createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn})    < ----------- Problem line
    .then((sessionCookie) => {
        // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
        const options = {maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true};
        res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'}));
    }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
});
```

On the `createSessionCookie` call, I get the following error & stack trace:

```
Error: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\CybeX\Bootstrap Studio Projects\future-design\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:44:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\CybeX\Bootstrap Studio Projects\future-design\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:90:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (C:\Users\CybeX\Bootstrap Studio Projects\future-design\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:149:16)
    at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (C:\Users\CybeX\Bootstrap Studio Projects\future-design\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:188:16)
    at C:\Users\CybeX\Bootstrap Studio Projects\future-design\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\auth-api-request.js:1570:49
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

This is part of the sign-in flow with a existing Gmail account.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching, Googling - I have seen the light.

For some additional context, this error featured heavily in my struggle "Firebase ID token has invalid signature." - I will get to that in a second.

Further, another issue I also faced was using a local auth emulator for web client-side (javascript), see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#android_ios_and_web_sdks) for setup.

**TL;DR to solve the immediate problem**

Client-side remained largely the same, however the documentation provided by Firebase was inaccurate/misleading - thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39193057/4628115) post, I found the solution. Thus, it follows...

**Which is the ID Token?** (Client-side):

The examples from here (to allow [signInWithPopup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk)), the response (if successful) results in

```
  ...
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
    var credential = result.credential;

    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    var token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // ...
  })
```

Looking for an idToken, I found one using `result.credential.idToken` but no where on the internet on **if** this was infact the **correct** token to use.

I ran into this error using the provided `idToken` above:

> Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected
> `"[insert your **projectId**]"` but got
> "59895519979-2l78aklb7cdqlth0eob751mdm67kt301.apps.googleusercontent.com".
> Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the
> service account used to authenticate this SDK.

Trying other tokens like `result.credential.accessToken` responded with various verification errors - what to do?

Mention earlier, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39193057/4628115) solution on Github suggested to use `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()` AFTER you have signed in. An example (building on my previous code) is to do the following:

```
  ...
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
      // current user is now valid and not null
      firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
          // send this ID token to your server
          const csrfToken = getCookie('_csrf');
          return postIdTokenToSessionLogin(idToken, csrfToken);
      })
  })
```

At this point, you can verify your token and `createSessionCookie`s to your heart's desire.

---

BUT, a secondary issue I unknowingly created for myself using the [Authentication Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#android_ios_and_web_sdks).

To setup for client-side use:

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
auth.useEmulator("http://localhost:9099");
```

To setup for hosting your firebase functions app (assuming you are using this with e.g. nodejs + express, see this for [setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#install_the_firebase_cli), *ask in comments, can provide more details if needed*)

Using Authentication Emulator caused the following errors AFTER using the above mentioned "fix". Thus, DO NOT RUN the local authentication emulator (with Google sign-in of a valid Google account) as you will consistently get.

> Firebase ID token has invalid signature. See
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for
> details on how to retrieve an ID token

You can use all your local emulators, but (so far in my experience) you will need to use an online authenticator.